# Table to set images on cover page, but text in the cell is not completly centred

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment

First of all, excuse my English. I'm trying to make a cover page, I have made it on Word, but in LateX is much harder to do. Is like this,

[image: This is what I need]

Same sized images at rigth and left of the text, textwidth size and centred text.

But this is what I can do on Latex. How can i make the text is centred in the cell?

[image: Latex table]

Here is the LateX Code:

```
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}| >   {\centering\arraybackslash}m{10cm}| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}| }
 \hline
 \mbox{}
 \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{US_ETSI_Logo} & 
 \textbf{{\large Universidad de Sevilla. Escuela Técnica Superior de Ingenieros}} &   \mbox{}     \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{UniversidadSevilla_Logo}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

maybe there is an easier solution to achieve what I want.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question: the text is centred both horizontally and vertically. Do you mean that you want a line break after *Sevilla.*?
In that case, the following will produce the desired output.

A few comments:

- To effect a line break inside a cell, you cannot use `\\` because `tabular` interprets it as a row terminator; however, you can---only in cells in paragraph mode, such as `m`, though---use `\linebreak` instead.
- You likely do not need a float environment (`table`) here. You want this particular `tabular` to stay at a very specific location (on the title page, I presume), not "float" somewhere else in your document. Using `\begin{table}{H}` is considered bad practice, except in very special cases. Just remove the `table` environment.
- You shouldn't specify both `width` and `height` of the images you import: if you don't get the ratio right, your images will appear distorted in your output document, which is not what you want here. Simply specify whichever is most important (probably `height` here), and leave the other one unspecified; the `graphicx` package will take care of the scaling for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
{
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{  |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|%
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10cm}|%
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|%
  }
    \hline
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{US_ETSI_Logo}
    & \large \bfseries Universidad de Sevilla
      \linebreak Escuela T\'{e}cnica Superior de Ingenieros
    & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{UniversidadSevilla_Logo}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Lose the `{}` around the `\large` text or you get the wrong line spacing.